# Как удалить товар из корзины woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть страница корзины на которой я вывожу все товары в корзине, но если пользователь захочет их удалить, они не удаляются. Хотя код вроде как срабатывает. Что нужно исправить?

```
 <div class="basket-product">
                <?php
                global $woocommerce;
                $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

                    foreach($items as $item => $values): ?>
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <div class="product-close" onclick="delete_item(<?php echo $values['product_id']?>)">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-title">
                            <div class="product-basket-img">
                                <?php
                                $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );
                                $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
                                //product image
                                $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
                                echo $getProductDetail->get_image();
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-basket-title">
                            <div class="product-basket-text">
                                <?php echo $_product->get_title() ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-text">
                            <div class="price-col">
                                <div class="price-col_text">
                                    Количество: 
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-col_number">
                                    <div class="price-minus">
                                        -
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price-quantities">
                                        <?php echo $values['quantity']; ?>  
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price-plus">
                                        +
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-actual">
                                Цена: 
                                <div class="price-number">
                                <?php echo $price;?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Код ajax-запроса для удаления

```
        <script>
function delete_item(product){
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/delete.php",
    type:"GET",
    data:{"product-id":product},
    dataType:"html",
    success: function Scs(response){
        alert('Товар удален из корзины!');
    }
});}
    </script>

<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item( intval($_GET['product_id'] ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, просто как идеи. Сам не сильно еще разбираюсь в теме. Возможно в файле delete.php надо заново создавать объект "cart" или "order" и уже к нему обращаться соответствующим методом удаления. Ну вообще, дебаг какой-то провести - очевидно что где-то какая-то инфа о заказе теряется.